# Ansible...SQLParseError: PostgreSQL does not support table with more than 3 dots

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I am editing and extending an ansible playbook built by third parts.

I added a task which runs a query on a DB and dumps the data into a csv file:

```
    - name: run query1 and dump data in csv
      community.postgresql.postgresql_copy:
        login_host: '{{ db_host }}'
        login_user: '{{ db_username }}'
        login_password: '{{ db_password }}'
        db: '{{ db_database }}'
        port: '{{ db_database_port }}'
        src: "{{ lookup('template', 'query1.sql.j2') }}"
        copy_to: "{{ log_base_path }}/results1.csv"
        options:
          format: csv
          delimiter: ';'
          header: yes
```

the content of `query1.sql.j2` is

```
SELECT
    KEY,
    idint,
    barcode,
    systemLV1,
    systemLV2,
    n.attribute1 AS attribute1_master,
    c.attribute1 AS attribute1_systemLV2,
    n.attribute2 AS attribute2_master,
    c.attribute2 AS attribute2_systemLV2,
    n.attribute3   AS attribute3_master,
    c.attribute3   AS attribute3_systemLV2,
    n.attribute1 = c.attribute1 AS check_attribute1_systemLV2,
    n.attribute2 = c.attribute2 AS check_attribute2_systemLV2,
    n.attribute3   = c.attribute3   AS check_attribute3_systemLV2

FROM 
    check_items_stechsystem2_ctrl2 c LEFT JOIN check_items_stechsystem1_ctrl2 n USING (KEY, idint, barcode, systemLV1) 
WHERE 
    (c.attribute1,c.attribute2,c.attribute3) != (n.attribute1,n.attribute2,n.attribute3);
```

when this task is runned, the following error is raised:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ansible_collections.community.postgresql.plugins.module_utils.database.SQLParseError: PostgreSQL does not support table with more than 3 dots

  localhost failed | msg: MODULE FAILURE

See stdout/stderr for the exact error
```

What is the meaning of it?

On the internet I can find little information about this error.

I read [in this issue page](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10007) that the error is somehow related to some non-ASCII character. If so, where should I look for a non-ASCII character which breaks my playbook ?

Both the tables in my query have the following structure:

```
Column  |   Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 

---------+----------+-----------+----------+---------

key     | text     |           | not null | 

idint   | text     |           |          | 

barcode     | text     |           |          | 

systemLV1 | integer  |           |          | 

systemLV2   | text     |           | not null | 

attribute1  | numeric  |           |          | 

attribute2  | smallint |           |          | 

attribute3    | bigint   |           |          |
```

But the text type columns are filled up by columns of the csv file which contain stringified numeric (eventually zero-padded) data.

When I manually run the query on the DB, I get no error, and the data don't carry any strange sign.

Comment: At a guess something in your stack is taking `query1.sql.j2` as a table name and is seeing it as <dbname>.<schema_name>.<table_name>. Postgres does not support cross database references in that manner, hence the error. I would suggest looking at the Postgres log to see if there is more information.

Comment: Have you tried running your query outside of an Ansible context? I'd suspect your `where` clause might not be something valid.

Comment: yes @β.εηοιτ.βε , at the end of the quesition: "When I manually run the query on the DB, I get no error, and the data don't carry any strange sign"

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I think this is unlikely, because I have other templates named the same (e.g. `systemLV2_ctrl2.sql.j2`) used with the same ansible module in the task raising the error (`community.postgresql.postgresql_copy`) and they do not raise any error.

Comment: Then look at the Postgres log and/or per the error message: *To see the full traceback, use -vvv.*. I don't see anything wrong with the query itself, so it looks to be the way it is being called.

Comment: Launching the playbook with the `-vvv` option does not give any further interesting information, and postgres logs at `/var/log/postgresql` do not show any error... but also no entry since before the playbook was launched-  and I have other tasks running queries on the DB.

Comment: Only thing I can think of at the moment  is determining what `"{{ lookup('template', 'query1.sql.j2') }}"` actually outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting all the **spaces** and **new lines** characters from the query solved the issue.

Replace `[\n\r]+` with   (space),

and then, replace    (double space) with   (space) iteratively.

Yet this is very weird since in that playbook there are other tasks which run queries with new line characters.

Since the Traceback indicates the issue is a `SQLParseError`, I guess some "bad" new line / tab / space character got into the query string while I was formatting it on some text editor.

Also it is possible that I have copied some parts of the query from some chat apps like MS Teams, which is a well known code spoiler.